# Could not load the image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.techlitellc.vfd"

Tags: ios

[image]

image is shown in viewcontroller.xib but not on simulator.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you just forgot the check the copy option while adding the image:

1. Delete image
2. Add again.
3. Check the "copy" option while adding

so it will copied to the resource

Answer (score 0):

Change the image format and save as PNG-24.

Answer (score -2):

First check if ViewController nib is loading properly try giving it background color or so.
and check viewDidLoad of the ViewController is getting called properly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.I will be more specific.